# Wait for the end of an asynchronous task

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I have a task that runs asynchronously, and I have a second method, right after that, that needs to retrieve the information from the asynchronous task. 
I can't modify the asynchronous task, so I wanted to know if it's possible to tell the second method to wait until the asynchronous method is finished.

```
foreach (AgentModel ag in Agents)
{
    if (ag.IsEnabledRow == true)
    {
        if (ag.IsSelected == true)
        {
            if (ag.selectedMatrice != null)
            {
                if (ag.selectedWeeks != null)
                {
                    //on vérifie le cycle choisi et on adapte la date en conséquence
                    semaineAAppliquer(ag);

                    ag.IsEnabledRow = false;

                    Task<int> attribuerPlanning = Gestion.AttrPlanning(
                        _dataService.ParamGlobaux.IDEtablissement,
                        _dataService.ParamGlobaux.Matricule,
                        _dataService.ParamGlobaux.ConnectionString,
                        ag.Matricule, ag.selectedMatrice.IDMatrice, DsCalendrierCongés,
                        dateDebutCycle, ag.dateFin, HoraireAZero, CompleterPriseVide,
                        RemplacerRH, JFRepos,
                        (text, title, buttons) => System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(
                            text, title, buttons), _progress, DecalageSemaine,
                            appliquerCouleur, _ToutEtablissement);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show($"Sélectionner une matrice pour" +
                    $" l'agent {ag.Nom}.");
            }
        }
    }
}

UpdateListeContrats();
```

The `attribuerPlanning` method is the asynchronous method, and I would like, without modifying the method itself, that it ends before calling `UpdateListeContrats`.

Or a way of saying `UpdateListeContrats`, don't trigger yourself until the other method is complete.

(Currently, `updateListeContrats` launches without having the information updated by the `attributerPlanning` method.)

Comment: Just put the await for the task attributePlanning. If updateListeContrats is out of scope of current method you can .Result for attributePlanning

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, you should virtually never "wait" (synchronous) for a task, but it is fine to "await" it (asynchronous).

In this case, the *most appropriate* place to do this is probably: at the call site, i.e.

```cs
if (ag.selectedWeeks != null)
{
    //on vérifie le cycle choisi et on adapte la date en conséquence
    semaineAAppliquer(ag);

    ag.IsEnabledRow = false;

    var result = await Gestion.AttrPlanning( ... );
}
```

In addition to being simple, this also avoids concurrency issues; most code is not anticipating concurrent usage in the same context.

In the general case, you *can* capture the task (etc) at one place, and await it later, but in *your case* the problem becomes what to do about the `foreach`/`if` etc; there could be zero, one, or many such tasks, if you are running them concurrently. But I guess you could throw them in a list, i.e.

```cs
var pending = new List<Task<int>>();
// ...
            pending.Add(attribuerPlanning);
// ...
var results = await Task.WhenAll(pending);
```

Comment: Also, he can use .Result if he does not want to make te method async (which is a good practice by the way), which I guess is the case :)

Comment: @EmilianoJavierGonzález accessing `.Result` is **not** a good idea; that's "sync over async", and it can be **actively harmful** (it is essentially the same as `.Wait()`)

Comment: Yes I know :) I was just remarking that using async, which is the correct way, is going to force him into making his method async :)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE: As Marc pointed out, don't do this if you have something that shouldn't or mustn't be blocked in the main thread, like a GUI.

You can do `attribuerPlanning.Wait();` after calling it.

Or if you want to run all task in the foreach async and wait all task to finish before UpdateListeContrats you can create a task list outside of the foreach:

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
```

and in the loop body add the current task to the list:

```
var task = Task.Run(() => Gestion.AttrPlanning(...) );
tasks.Add(task);
```

and outside of foreach do

```
Task.WhenAll(tasks).Wait();
UpdateListeContrats();
```

Comment: `.Wait()` (and `.Result`) is (are) "sync-over-async", which is very dangerous in many scenarios - it should almost always be avoided if even remotely possible; it is usually a sign that you're shoe-horning async (or sync, depending on your perspective) into a place where it *doesn't fit*

Comment: ".Wait() (and .Result) is (are) "sync-over-async", which is very dangerous in many scenarios"  A hammer can be dangerous too in many situations :) but you are right in this case, I've just checked his code again, and it seems that there is some GUI stuff going on that shouldn't be blocked by Wait(). I update my answer to not do this.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay The outer task will finish when the inner is finished. It works for me, or I miss something?

Comment: @jojess No, you are correct in that respect; `Task.Run` has an overload that accepts `Func<Task>` which returns the inner `Task` rather than wrapping it. It doesn't escape the fact that `Task.Run` and `Task.Wait` are nothing more than workarounds when there is no option but to call async code from a sync context. Both have their negatives e.g. `Task.Wait` can cause deadlocks, but you make no mention of this. The proper solution, when possible, is to await the tasks as per Marc's answer.